# Blocking Requests using HTTP_ORIGIN to Prevent Spamming

Tags: apache, http, post, https, server

Over the last couple days I've been getting millions of requests from rotating IPs. They're attempting to run post requests and seem to be using an incorrect HTTP_ORIGIN. By incorrect, I mean that it's not the same as what my server sends:

- My server sends: "https://www.example.com"
- The spam request sends: www.example.com

I placed some logging for each scenario:

1. **User logged in** and has **incorrect HTTP_ORIGIN**
2. **User NOT logged in** and has **incorrect HTTP_ORIGIN**

What I've noticed is that there are users that are logged in, but have the wrong HTTP_ORIGIN (origin is missing "https://". I have checked those user accounts and while they appear to be real, and not created by the original spam requests, they may be currently run through scripts.

It seems like it would prevent those users from accessing the POST requests of the site, but on the other hand, if they were real users, it would cause a problem.

Now if I were to put filtering in place to block requests that didn't match the origin, my questions are:

1. What would be the side effect of that?
2. Are there downsides or negative aspects?
3. Would I see drops in traffic?

Comment: I have another question, does your http domain automatically redirects to https then it do an ssl handshake (when using a normal browser like firefox)?

Comment: @MobrineHayde Yes it does...

Comment: But since we're talking about a POST request, anyone sending a POST to HTTP and not HTTPS would mean that it wasn't done on my site because every page uses HTTPS. I would assume that the HTTP_ORIGIN—if truly from my site—would correct to the HTTPS:// version of the origin and not HTTP://... is that accurate or true?

Comment: Yes, that's true, and that's what I said in my response, but if a user is using a normal tcp client not wrapped to ssl (whether he is real client or not) it would still have 'http' and will be considered for you an incorrect HTTP_ORIGIN

Comment: There is also another way to check if my answer is true or false, consider using a tool like curl or wget to try to parse you website with 'http' scheme and 'https' scheme, if the response is the same, that means my response can still be considered acceptable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that so, It's like you said some are using your website from scripts, considering if your website is normal (I mean not like a website to upload data or sth like that), then it would be good to consider adding captcha to your website in place of filtering requests (cause I think it would be simple for those who send incorrect HTTP_ORIGIN to make a similar one to the original if they use a sslstream especially if it is for malicious goals).

And for the consequences if you use a filtering to the http request, I think the requests will drop remarkably (since you will refuse incorrect ones), and some real users who use scripts will switch to browser (it's a rare case especially if they **scrape** data from website in an automatic way) or they will stop using your website.

You need to wait for further research and make sure that those false requests are not malicious ones (perhaps they are using simple tcp client). Either way it is best for the time being to inspect data sent in the POST requests (incorrect ones) and see if there is some suspicious data (In that case you should use some safety method in your website)

Comment: I can't say 100% that they are using scripts or scraping, but considering they're real accounts it is probable... Captcha is one method I'm adding to the POST request Ajax forms. There is definitely suspicious data and that's how I know that it's spam (e.g. ohppu5574c3x6rk@h8vl2l8m.com). If these were real users there would be a surge in actual site traffic.